# How to get a list of broken images with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the console I have 180 failed to load resources, I need to get a list of these resources so that I can send a report to the webmaster with the images URLs. How can this be done?

Comment: Copy and paste the list from the console ?

Comment: I want this to be done automatically

Comment: Grab the 404 errors from your logs.

Comment: @halfer how can I do so?

Comment: Well, your logs are text files, so how you process them is up to you. You could run them through "Analog" and put it into machine output mode, and parse that output. Or use a special query string and grep for that string plus "404" in the same line.

Comment: `if(!img.width) { magic }`

Comment: jQuery has an .error() method you can use, but creating a script that automatically gets all failed links and mails them to webmasters, is going to be a lot more work than just a few lines of jQuery.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you want this report to be generated from the client side. If I understood well, you want the report to be sent each time a client accesses to the web site, right? If that's so, you can use the approaches catching errors that were described above and then have javascript send an ajax request to a server script that will send the report to the webmaster.

Comment: They are images of youtube videos, I need to know once a video is removed from youtube, and I'm doing this by checking the existence of a video thumbnail.

Comment: Checking this via JS is more brittle than accessing logs - and the webmaster should be checking their 404s and other failures anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a script to the page, you can bind a handler to the `error` event and track all failures:

```
$(function(){
  var errorImages = [];

  $('img').on('error', function(){
                errorImages.push(this.src);
              });

  $(window).on('load', function(){
    alert(errorImages);
  });
});
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/iboyik/3

If you want to get all failed images on a page that is already loaded, that is a little trickier. I was able to do that by reloading all images:

```
(function(){
  var errorImages = [];
  $('img')
    .on('error', function(){
                    errorImages.push(this.src);
                 })
    .prop('src', function(i, src){return src;});
  // wait for all images to fail (bit of a hack)
  setTimeout(function(){alert(errorImages);}, 1000);
})();
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/iboyik/2

Answer (score 2):

You can easily track images that fail to load, as long as you set up an event listener before the image starts to load. Like this:

```
img.addEventListener('error', function() {
  //report failed image
}, false);
```

If all of your images are loaded in `<img>` tags that are in the html, you can set up an error event for all of them in a script. Just make sure the script that sets this up is placed after the img tags, but do not run the setup in a page load event or `DOMContentLoaded` because you may have missed some error events, and it will be too late.

See this example:

http://jsbin.com/ekiram/2/edit

If you want, you can set up a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) event to watch for any new `<img>` elements added dynamically and set up an error event there. But it won't work in all browsers.

You can check whether an image has loaded by looking at the `naturalWidth` property. If it's 0, it hasn't loaded. But there's no way to know whether the image has actually failed to load or is just taking a really long time, like if there's a slow network connection. I suppose you could use this if you have another way to know if the page and all images are really done loading, like after a page `load` event or if you're willing to set a very long timeout.